# Control Template Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, resourcedictionary

I have bindings on certain elements on the below defined Control Template, this template is defined in my custom ResourceDictionary and is assigned as the template for a ContentControl in MainPage.xaml, what I want to do is bind to the element properties that I want to change the values of in the Code-Behind MainPage by Resistering DependencyProperties, the problem is it is not working, for instance using a getter in code for "GPBaseBannerImage".Source returns null, obviously it found nothing...., i think the binding is wrong in the template definition of my ResourceDictionary....

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GPBaseTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Canvas x:Name="GPBaseCanvas" 
                Background="{StaticResource GPBaseBgBrush}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Image x:Name="GPBaseBannerImage" Source="{Binding Source}" 
                   Stretch="{Binding Stretch}"/>
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>

            <Grid x:Name="GPBaseGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                     <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="50" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>

                <StackPanel x:Name="GPBaseContentPanel"
                            Background="{Binding Background}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalAlignment}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                            Width="{Binding Width}"
                            Height="{Binding Height}"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"/>

                <StackPanel x:Name="GPBaseBtnPanel"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1">

                    <Button x:Name="GPBaseBtn_1"
                            Style="{StaticResource GPBaseBtnStyle}"
                            Background="{Binding Background}"
                            Click="{Binding Click}"/>

                    <Button x:Name="GPBaseBtn_2"
                            Style="{StaticResource GPBaseBtnStyle}"
                            Background="{Binding Background}"
                            Click="{Binding Click}"/>

                    <Button x:Name="GPBaseBtn_3"
                            Style="{StaticResource GPBaseBtnStyle}"
                            Background="{Binding Background}"
                            Click="{Binding Click}"/>

                    <Button x:Name="GPBaseBtn_4"
                            Style="{StaticResource GPBaseBtnStyle}"
                            Background="{Binding Background}"
                            Click="{Binding Click}"/>

                    <Button x:Name="GPBaseBtn_5"
                            Style="{StaticResource GPBaseBtnStyle}"
                            Background="{Binding Background}"
                            Click="{Binding Click}"/>

                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

        </Canvas>
    </ContentPresenter>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I do not think I am using it correctly as I get an unhandled exception, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What is the error in output view?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Comment: Do you check all your binding property is correct?
What is the reference from click binding?

Comment: That's all i have, i am not 100% sure how to use it, i want to beable to change the binded properties from page.xaml for example

Comment: The reason I created the template is because I want a consistent layout for the app with the ability to change some properties on varying pages

Comment: So we will debug step by step, remove part per part of your code and test. Begin with remove the GPBaseGrid

Comment: Ok no more error, please see the code edits, although I did not want the grid taken out.

Comment: I fixed the exceptions, the problem was not the grid it was the definition of the Buttons Click property. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my problem, I needed to set the DataContext on the object that was using my custom template, in this case it was a ContentControl, but setting the DataContext on the control in Xaml did not work for some reason, I had to set it in code behind and then call NotifyPropertyChanged in the property setter(set; Not Xaml Setter) of GPBaseTemplateHelper.

```
    public MainMenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BaseTemplateHelper = new GPBaseTemplateHelper();

        if (BaseTemplateHelper != null)
        {
            this.DataContext = BaseTemplateHelper;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close arrow, it is just a error of paste or ?

```
<Image x:Name="GPBaseBannerImage" Source="{Binding Source}" 
               Stretch="{Binding Stretch} <----- ???
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

*** ControlTemplate Usage ***

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="GPMainMenuContentControl" 
                 Template="{Binding Source={StaticResource GPBaseTemplate} }" >


 </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Can you put your xaml code that you use for this template please